# im unable to open a folder path from txt file in photoshop javascript (JSX)

Tags: javascript, jsx, photoshop-script

```
main();
function main(){
    var listFile = File("~/Desktop/Testpath.txt"); 
    if(listFile == null) return;
    listFile.open('r') ; 
    var listString = listFile.read(); 
    listFile.close(); 
    fileList = listString;
    // "selectedPSD" Shuld Open "listString" Folder
    var selectedPSD =  File.openDialog("Select a PSD file to open" );

if (selectedPSD!=undefined) app.open(selectedPSD);
};
```

By Defold it Navigates last open folder
but I want to navigate it in my txt document path
this is inside the txt document
I want to navigate in dis folder

```
/c/Program%20Files/Common%20Files
```

this is giving me the folder `fileList`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.openDlg()` method of a Folder object instead:

```
var path = new Folder("/c/Program%20Files/Common%20Files");
var myFiles = path.openDlg(); // <--
alert(myFiles);
```